# stream screen to chromecast using Presentation

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3 to develop an app that stream the screen to the TV using chromecast.

The problem is that when i retrieve the presentationDisplay it is null!
I'm using default receiver app and it seems that chromecast does not support

```
MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO
```

This is the code:

```
private void updatePresentation() {

        Log.d(TAG, "updatePresentation()");

        MediaRouter.RouteInfo route = mMediaRouter.getSelectedRoute();
        Display presentationDisplay = route != null ? route.getPresentationDisplay() : null;

        Log.d(TAG, "MediaRouter.RouteIngo: " + route.getName());

        if (presentationDisplay != null)
            Log.d(TAG, "presentationDisplay " + presentationDisplay.getName());
        else if (presentationDisplay == null)
            Log.d(TAG, "presentationDisplay is null");

        // Dismiss the current presentation if the display has changed.
        if (mPresentation != null && mPresentation.getDisplay() != presentationDisplay) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Dismissing presentation because the current route no longer "
                    + "has a presentation display.");
            mPresentation.dismiss();
            mPresentation = null;
        }

        // Show a new presentation if needed.
        if (mPresentation == null && presentationDisplay != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Showing presentation on display: " + presentationDisplay);
            mPresentation = new DemoPresentation(this, presentationDisplay);
            mPresentation.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
                {
                    if (mPresentation != null) mPresentation.dismiss();
                }
            });
            try {
                Log.d("mPresentation", "showing");
                mPresentation.show();
            } catch (WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException ex) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Couldn't show presentation!  Display was removed in "
                        + "the meantime.", ex);
                mPresentation = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you manually connect your device to the Chromecast via Chromecast's Miracast-style support? This does not happen automatically, nor does it happen as a result of working with `MediaRouter`.

Comment: If i correctly understood what you are saying: on my own nexus 10 i used Chromecast App to setup the chromecast device and on my nexsus 4 all happened automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on my own nexus 10 i used Chromecast App to setup the chromecast device and on my nexsus 4 all happened automatically.

No, I am not referring to just the Chromecast app.

Chromecast natively supports the Cast SDK and `RemotePlaybackClient`. It also supports serving as an external display, which can be used for `Presentation`. However, the *user* has to *manually* go into Settings > Displays > Cast Screen and choose the Chromecast. Then, you will get screen mirroring, and `Presentation` will work.

Comment: ok, but it's not what i need. I need a button in my app and when a user click on that button the screen mirroring has to start. Like "Screen Mirroring" section into Chromecast App. Or in another way, launching an Intent to start screen mirroring.

Comment: @Matt: "I need a button in my app and when a user click on that button the screen mirroring has to start" -- AFAIK, that is not possible. "launching an Intent to start screen mirroring" -- you can [try `ACTION_CAST_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_CAST_SETTINGS) to take the user to Settings > Displays > Cast Screen.

Comment: Actually what i need is not documented anyware but why google can do that into its app Chromecast App ("Screen Mirroring" Section) ? Using a custom blue button in the middle of the layout the Chromecast App can start/stop screen mirroring.

Comment: @Matt: Google's apps routinely can do things that ordinary apps cannot.